# Why is my accessibility label not reading with pause in between despite using comma separator in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility

Swift - Accessibility label is not reading with pause in between text

Hi all,

I am currently facing one issue where my accessibility label is not reading with pause in between even though comma separator is given.

So I added like this

```
let count = 7

labelview.accessibilityLabel = "User count updated: \(count), , , ,"
```

It should read as User count updated 7 ( with some pause ) and then text.
Instead its reading continuously.Any help would be appreciated

I also tried with dots and \n but same result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm5KT.png

Comment: There's no text after the commas. What's the point of the `, , , ,` at the end?

Comment: I want small gap between on reading the label  and type so I added there, is there right way @HangarRash

So it should read as User count updated 7 ( with some pause )  Text

Comment: What "type" are you referring to? You also stated *"It should read as User count updated 7 ( with some pause ) and then text."*. What text are you referring to? If you have an accessibility label with a value such as `"Some stuff, more stuff"`, then there will be a pause between "Some stuff" and "more stuff". But it all has to be in the same accessibility label.

Comment: I want a pause between the accessibility label and type reading by voice over 
@HangarRash

So I added this line, opened Xcode accessibility inspector , focused the label to read, 

But the content for me is to read this text and type with some pause in-between.But current implementation I can't able to read

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm5KT.png

Sample image attached for your clarity

Comment: The type is just information you see in the Xcode inspector. On a real device which has VoiceOver enabled, the type isn't spoken for a label. Test on a real device so you know what will actually happen.

Comment: Ok , let me check on real device and update then

Comment: But I tried with button for same case in real device its reading the type without space

I need label or button but to have a small pause in reading between the label and type @HangarRash

Comment: For Text it won't read the type. For Button it will. But it says something like "Your name. Button" - clearly as 2 sentences. I wouldn't recommend to alter this behavior, as this is what actual voiceover users are used to hear. Maybe explain why does it bug you, so we can propose the solutions to the actual issue you are trying to resolve with this workaround

Comment: I agree with comments so far. [WCAG 4.1.2 Name, Role, Value](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#name-role-value) is working as expected and announcing the name (accessible name, label) of the element, the role of the element, and optionally the value or state of the element. Don't try to change that.

Comment: Ok, I have requirement from client to do that changes so only I posted to have any method we can adopt.

If that is standard and professional way we can go with that